# Vscode with beautify does not indent django html templates

Tags: html, django, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I am looking to format my django templates in the same manner as HTML.

Beautify ends up treating my templates like text, and not indenting their contents.

For example, after formatting my code looks like this:

```html
<head>
  {% if title %}
  <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
  {% else %}
  <title>Django Blog</title>
  {% endif %}
</head>
```

Instead of

```html
<head>

  {% if title %}
    <title>Django Blog - {{ title }}</title>
  {% else %}
    <title>Django Blog</title>
  {% endif %}
</head>
```

I currently have Beautify & Django extensions installed, running on VSCode and WSL.

`settings.json` VSCode:

```json
    "files.associations": {
        "**/*.html": "html",
        "**/templates/*/*.html": "django-html",
        "**/templates/*": "django-txt",
        "**/requirements{/**,*}.{txt,in}": "pip-requirements"
    },
    "emmet.includeLanguages": {
        "django-html": "html"
    },
    "beautify.language": {
        "html": [
            "htm",
            "html",
            "django-html"
        ]
    },
    "[django-html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "HookyQR.beautify"
    }
```

Why isn't beautify correctly formatting / indenting my templates? How can I resolve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Django Template Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=junstyle.vscode-django-support) extension for VSCode.

Answer (score -3):

You can simply right click in HTML file and click format it will automatically ident your file. Actually these extension make vscode auto ident feature active but still you have to do it manually.